Conway Polynomial for p=2, n=3?
Im doing an exercise on Conway polynomials. As far as im concerned, for p=2, n=3 both
$f(x)=x^3 + x^2 + 1$
and
$g(x)=x^3 + x + 1$
satisfy every condition. According to every source i found, the latter is the correct one with respect to the ordering, which is given as:
"Before defining which of the possible $f(X)$ is the Conway polynomial we introduce an ordering of the polynomials of degree $n$ over $GF(p)$. Let $g(X) = g_nX^n + ... + g_0$ and $h(X) = h_nX^n + ... + h_0$. Then we define $g < h$ if and only if there is an index $k$ with $g_i = h_i$ for $i > k$ and $(-1)^{n-k} g_k < (-1)^{n-k} h_k$. The Conway polynomial is the smallest polynomial of degree n with respect to this ordering [which satisfies the other conditions]."
Now im really confused, certainly $f_3=g_3$, so $k=2$, thus $n-k = 1$, and $-g_2 < -f_2$ should hold in order for $g < f$, but it doesnt.
Certainly, $f$ and $g$ are irreducible and primitive w.r.t to $GF(2)$, and since $3$ is prime they are compatible too. Where am I wrong?

You should give a bibliographical/web sound reference to Conway polynomials.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_polynomial_(finite_fields) has the exact same definition as the (non-public) script im working with.

The Wikipedia article first wants to map a polynomial (with the signs alternating)
$$a_dx^d-a_{d-1}x^{d-1}+a_{d-2}x^{d-1}+\cdots$$
to the tuple $a_da_{d-1}\ldots a_0$, and then compare lexicographically.
Here $x^3+x^2+1$ corresponds to the sequence $1101$ and $x^3+x+1$ to $1011$. The latter is earlier lexicographically.
May be you were confused by the fact that in $\Bbb{F_p}$ we have $-a=p-a$, and the latter is used for the purposes of sorting. Over $\Bbb{F}_2$ in particular we have $a=-a$ for all $a\in\Bbb{F}_2$.
I am not an authority on this. But that's how I read the definition.

Testing it. Over $\Bbb{F}_3$, the monic primitive quadratic polynomials are $x^2+2x+2$ and its reciprocal divided by two, $x^2+x+2$. Here sign alternation kicks in, the coefficients of the degree one terms are flipped, and the respective sequences are $112$ and $122$. Therefore $x^2+2x+2$ comes earlier in the lexicon.

Observe that norm compatibility played no role in the two small examples I looked at (both prime fields have a unique primitive element). I am not fluent enough with this definition, and hence somewhat reluctant to attempt to answer.

^$-a=p-a$, only if $a\neq0$. Naturally $-0=0$.

Are you aware of competitors to Conway polynomials ?

Thanks for your help, indeed i simply forgot (-1)*1 was supposed to be done in $GF(2)$ as well.
